# Which tense should be used in troubleshooting cases, simple present or simple past?

Tags: tenses, dates, present-tense

Which tense should be used in troubleshooting cases, simple present or simple past?

I've seen examples where simple present is used. But what if a specific date is provided in the case.

For example:

> On September 9, 2013, the system encounters/encountered an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. If you were describing it as it happens, think a security officer enters an entry on his log, you should use present tense.

> 9:03pm. Mr White leaves the storeroom with 3 Erlenmeyer flasks.

1. If you are describing it in reference to an event previously happened, simple past should be used.

> At 9:03pm, Mr. White left the storeroom with 3 Erlenmeyer flasks.

On your example, encountered should be used as you are pointing out an event happened in the past.

Comment: I think OP's question is: Is it permissible to use the [Historical Present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) in this case.